Azure B2C SMS Pricing
If i have 1000 users (all users are active) in B2C local account and configured SMS based authentication.
If the users are login attempts 2 or 3 times per day. so, the sms attempts for 3000 times for this tenant per day. approximately 90,000 SMS requests per month.
I have 2 B2C tenants.
What is the approximate billing for month for this scenario for this 2 tenants and how to calculate and where we saw this billing related information in azure b2c tenant.
Tenant 1

Tenant 2

Here shows the billable units per authentication for tenant 1 and monthly active users for
tenant 2.

At least for the Monthly Active Users model, this is what they say on the pricing page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory-external-identities/

A flat fee of $0.03 is billed for each SMS/Phone-based multi-factor authentication attempt.

This was with East US data center and US Dollar as currency.
So with 90k SMS/month = $2700.
